# How to access every single line of textarea coming from a form blob?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, textarea

I am developing a Google Apps Script web app which shows a form the user can fill out. The data is send then to the App Script via [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) where it is processed.

However one UI element in the form is a `<textarea>` and I want to get every single line separately. But when I access the data I get only a string without any linebreaks.

```
function processForm(formData){
let data = formData.textAreaName; // only a string without linebreaks
}
```

How to I get the line breaks so that I can parse every single line?

Comment: Hm, I usually parse the form data before sending it to the server, so the problem is avoided. Can you make an exception for the textarea and pass its value separately from the main form?

Comment: well yea that would be the worst case however, I am adding `formData.textAreaName` into another html in a `<span>` element with `white-space: pre-line;" and the line breaks are preserved there. So that means the information is there.

Comment: Are the line breaks showing before converted to blob?

Comment: yes but not after. Well I get now the textarea separately and pass it to the apps script. this works.

Comment: @zlZimon - that's interesting. This would mean that under the hood, the value of the `<textarea>` element is stripped of newlines ( as `value` property should return new lines as well ). This caught my interest - will test today

Comment: @zlZimon - could you show your setup? Runtime, client-side code, etc. I made a test version myself, and newlines are passed correctly, example output server-side: `{ textarea: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6', text: '' }`.

Comment: How do you verify that those '\n' linebreaks are there? Do you see the output in the Strackdriver logs? Maybe the problem is that I do not know how to veryfiy, When I use Logger.log those \n are not there and there is also no linebreak in the logs.

Comment: Well, via stackdriver, executions tab, browser console and `split("\n")`. All confirm that the form is passed correctly - are you running Rhino runtime by any chance?

Comment: no I am not running Rhino

Comment: @zlZimon - well, one more question then - what's the browser that accesses the client? Also, it might help if we know what `JSON.stringify` returns and how the client-side page markup and code looks like.

Comment: I use chrome. I think the issue is just that those linebreaks are removed when displaying the string f.e. in the logs. When I retrieve the char code of each character I can see all the linebreaks: `Logger.log(formData.textAreaName.split("").map(function(ch) { return ch + "(" + ch.charCodeAt(0) + ")";}).join(", "));`